# AngularJS override htmlAnchor directive

Tags: angularjs, wordpress

Is it possible to override the default angularjs behavior when handling anchor tags ? I've added an angularjs theme to wordpress using the jsonapi plugin to return the page content but when logged into wordpress, I'd like the "Edit this page" link to take me back into the wordpress dashboard, but angularjs has made all links on the page to html5 pushstate to change the url so I'm not brought into the wp dashboard.

I'd like to be able to override the directive that handles 'a' elements so that the 'restrict' property is set to 'C' rather than 'E', then explicitly set the class name on anchor tags I want to use pushstate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [terminal](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-terminal-) property of DDO.

> **terminal**
>
> If set to true then the current priority will be the last set of
>   directives which will execute (any directives at the current priority
>   will still execute as the order of execution on same priority is
>   undefined). Note that expressions and other directives used in the
>   directive's template will also be excluded from execution.

Working example that overrides default AngularJS `a` directive: http://plnkr.co/edit/DssX2EAB2ulvYUQl2ggS?p=preview (clicking on "test" refresh page, that normally is prevented by AngularJS)

But actually, default `a` directive, [does not change](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/a.js) behaviour if element has `href` attribute.